# Integrating IIS 7 and Glassfish server

Tags: iis, glassfish

I'm trying to integrate IIS 7 and glassfish server.
So that the webpages from my web app are pulled up from the glassfish server over the internet.

Comment: Welcome at SO, but please read the FAQ before posting questions. Now we know what you're trying, but what is your question? Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a blog post about this.  It's pretty simple to do.  All you need to do is install a server farm to route your requests to Glassfish instead.  Check this post out for more detailed instructions.

http://jstoup.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/how-to-integrate-glassfish-with-iis/